# SqlCacheDependency with SqlCommand not working

Tags: asp.net, sqlcachedependency

Having problems with implementing very basic SqlCacheDependency prototype.

Have tried this with a sproc but now I'm down to straight command execution.

```
    public SqlCommand GetReadCommand(int ID)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT dbo.Entity.Entity_ID, dbo.Entity.Name FROM dbo.Entity WHERE Entity_ID = @ID", _conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("ID", ID));

        return cmd;
    }

    public SqlCacheDependency GetSqlDependency(int ID)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = GetReadCommand(ID);
        SqlCacheDependency dep = new SqlCacheDependency(cmd);
        return dep;
    }
```

And I'm reading a dataset of all objects and creating a very simple dependency test on some data I inserted manually:

```
    public DataSet SelectAll()
    {
        DataSet result;
        if (_cache["Entity_FullSet"] == null)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.GetAllEntities", _conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            _conn.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            result = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(result);


            _cache[MasterCacheKey()] = DateTime.Now;
            string[] mk = new[] { MasterCacheKey() };
            CacheDependency cd = new CacheDependency(null, mk);

            SqlCacheDependency scd = new SqlCacheDependency(GetReadCommand(1));
            CacheDependency[] cds = new[] { cd, scd };

            AggregateCacheDependency acd = new AggregateCacheDependency();
            acd.Add(acd);

            _cache.Insert("Entity_FullSet", result, scd);
            _conn.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            result = (DataSet)_cache["Entity_FullSet"];
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The 'master key' is there for testing aggregate cache dependencies - changing it works great, but the sql dependency on 1 (variable scd) simply isn't working.  If I go and update the table - even delete the row - nothing happens, the cache isn't cleared.

[image]

Any ideas as to why the sql dependency isn't registering/firing would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you enabled service broker in the DB, and turned on query notifications?

```
ALTER DATABASE [YourDB] SET ENABLE_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

In Application_Start():

```
SqlDependency.Start(connectionString)
```

And call Stop() in Application_End().

Can you post the code for your stored procedure? Do you by any chance have `SET NOCOUNT ON` at the beginning of your SP? If so, that will prevent query notifications.

For the code as posted above, try replacing those 3-part column names with one or two-part names. For example, replace "dbo.Entity.Entity_ID" with "Entity_ID" or (better) "e.Entity_ID" (after assigning the alias "e" to dbo.Entity).

Comment: I had not set those things - maybe I missed something obvious but in my reads of the classes documentation I don't recall coming across that alter database statement.  Trying it now.

Comment: Oh - WRT the sproc - I titled this badly I think - at first I thought it was sprocs, but then I tried it with a direct sql statement and still no joy.

Comment: Thanks, it was a combination of that simple thing plus I need my dependency to be on the same cmd executed.